# Yama took birth as Vidura, then who was performing the work of Yama as god of death?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, devatas

1. Since Yama had taken birth as Vidura, then while he was alive on earth as Vidura , who was performing the work of him as god of death ?
2. My second question is related to first, can Devtas like - Varuna, Indra, Yama, Vaayu, etc. take birth on earth, if yes as seen in example of Vidura, who perform their normal work as devtas while they are alive on earth ?

Comment: Please remove the third question, else it will contain multiple questions.

Comment: Lord Indra took birth as Arjuna.. but still Arjuna met Indra in Swarga Loka.. similar case..

Comment: @Tezz Arjun was son of Indra , not Indra.